# Why the "backface-visibility" can effect other element when their parent transform with scale?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is an element and it uses transform for scale. In the element, there are two child element. The first is the table and second is div. The div style set **backface-visibility: hidden** and **display: hidden**.When hovering the table, show the div. And can see the table render a litter different like before, like the div style effect the table style.

[The backface-visibility has no effect on 2D transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility), why it can affect other elements?

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip">
    this is tooltip
  </div>
</div>
```

scss

```
.container {
  transform: scale(0.77);

  .table table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    tr, td {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      padding: .5em 1em;
    }
  }

  .tooltip {
    position: absolute
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }

  .tooltip.active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

js

```
const table = document.querySelector('table')

const tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip')


table.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  tooltip.classList.add('active')
})

table.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  tooltip.classList.remove('active')
})
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/oustn/pen/zQezNL)

**PS**

Different browser render result:

- Firefox(65.0.2)

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8XTZ.png)
[show tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GubQl.png)

- Chrome(74.0.3729.169)
  [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSG8D.png)
  [show tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gksmu.png)
- Edge
  [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mdrr.png)
  [show tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJdak.png)

And the edge looks like is the best in this situation.

Comment: I can not see any difference on the table when hovering over it on firefox.

Comment: @Persijn Yes, maybe is related to the browser.